# Can I add tf.keras.backend function in TensorFlow "custom" layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

TensorFlow can implement Keras with `tf.keras`.

Keras has three backend implementations available: the TensorFlow backend, the Theano backend, and the CNTK backend.

If I wanted to build a custom layer, can I add `tf.keras.backend.theano.tensor.dot` and `tf.keras.backend.theano.gradient.disconnected_grad` in call function?

For example, there is one program in TensorFlow（https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_layers）：

```py
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_variable("kernel", 
                                    shape=[int(input_shape[-1]), 
                                           self.num_outputs])

    def call(self, input):
        return tf.matmul(input, self.kernel)
```

Can I change call function into:

```py
def call(self, input):
    return tf.keras.backend.theano.tensor.dot(self.kernel,tf.keras.backend.theano.gradient.disconnected_grad(input))
```

Comment: I think the best way to know a question about "can" is to try it, have you tried it?

Comment: tf.keras doesn't have the theano backend, only the full keras has it